# Cant get value from json in google maps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, google-maps

I'm a newbie in programming, I'm trying to show user location after clicking on the checkbox, but when I check in inspect element->network it's show null and nothing happens. any solution?
[This is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taajo.png)
here is my checkbox code:

```
<li>
        <div class="collapsible-header text-small-screen">PETUGAS</div>
        <div class="main-menu-body collapsible-body">
        <form id="frmposisi">
            <?php
            echo '<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">';
            foreach($unor as $key_unor=>$row_unor){
                echo '<li>';
                echo "<div class='collapsible-header text-small-screen'>".@$row_unor->nama_unor."</div>";
                echo "<div class='main-menu-body collapsible-body'>";
                    
            //      echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='posisi_".@$row_unor->id_unor."' value='posisi_".@$row_unor->id_unor."' id='posisi_".@$row_unor->id_unor."'><label for='posisi_".@$row_unor->id_unor."'> Pegawai</label></p>";
                    
                
                    if (@$row_unor->posisi){
                        foreach($row_unor->posisi as $key_posisi=>$row_posisi){
                            echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='posisi_".@$row_unor->id_unor."#".@$row_posisi->id_posisi."' id='posisi_".@$row_unor->id_unor."#".@$row_posisi->id_posisi."' value='".@$row_unor->id_unor."#".@$row_posisi->id_posisi."' onclick='load_position(this)' class='map-btn btn-qlue-sort'><label for='posisi_".@$row_unor->id_unor."#".@$row_posisi->id_posisi."'>".@$row_posisi->nama_posisi."</label></p>";
                        }
                    }
                echo "</div>";
                echo '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            ?>
        </form>
        </div>
    </li>
```

my controller:

```
function load_position()
{
    $result = $this->model_web->get_geomaps();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

my model:

```
function get_geomaps(){
    $post_data = $this->input->post('id_pegawai');
    $date = new DateTime($this->input->post("tgl_tracking"));
    $partition = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    if($post_data){
        $arr_posisi = array();
        foreach($post_data as $key=>$val){
            if (strpos($key,'posisi') !== false) {
                if($val){
                    $arr_val = explode("#", $val);
                    $id_unor = $arr_val[0];
                    $id_posisi = $arr_val[1];
                    $arr_unor[] = $id_unor;
                    $arr_posisi[] = $id_posisi;
                }
            }
        }
        $tgl_name = (int)str_replace("-","",date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post("tgl_tracking").' +1 day')));
        $this->db->select('MAX(a.id_log) as id_log,a.id_pegawai,c.nama_pegawai,c.alamat_pegawai,c.no_hp,c.wilayah_kerja,c.id_unor,c.nama_unor,
        (select e.lat FROM t_geomaps PARTITION (p'.$tgl_name.') e where DATE_FORMAT(e.insert_date,"%Y-%m-%d") = "'.$this->input->post("tgl_tracking").'" and e.id_pegawai=c.id_pegawai order by e.insert_date desc limit 1) as lat,
        (select e.lng FROM t_geomaps PARTITION (p'.$tgl_name.') e where DATE_FORMAT(e.insert_date,"%Y-%m-%d") = "'.$this->input->post("tgl_tracking").'" and e.id_pegawai=c.id_pegawai order by e.insert_date desc limit 1) as lng,
        (select b.status from absen_log b where b.id_log=max(a.id_log)) as status');
        $this->db->join('m_pegawai c','c.id_pegawai=a.id_pegawai');
        $this->db->where_in('c.id_unor',$arr_unor);
        $this->db->where_in('c.id_posisi',$arr_posisi);
        $this->db->where('DATE_FORMAT(a.date_log,"%Y-%m-%d") = "'.$this->input->post("tgl_tracking").'"');
        $this->db->group_by('a.id_pegawai');
        $result = $this->db->get('absen_log a')->result();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

My database:
[table absen_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYpbP.png)

[table m_pegawai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNBmi.png)

[table t_geomaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta2wx.png)

Comment: You've used `$this->input->post('id_pegawai')` and there doesn't seem to be any `<input/>` that has its `name` set to `id_pegawai`, all the input names are set to something like `posisi_....`.

Comment: i'm trying to used `$post_data = $this->input->post('posisi_".@$row_unor->id_unor."#".@$row_posisi->id_posisi."');` but the result still null.